# How a static variable is accessible before the declaration?

Tags: java, static-variables, class-variables

```
public class Main {

    static int x = Main.y;
//  static int x = y; //Not allowed; y is not defined
    static int y = x;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(x);//prints 0
    }
}
```

How come I am allowed to use y trough the class, but not directly?

When is y defined?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The precise rules governing forward reference to class variables are described in the section [§8.3.2.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#287406) of the JLS:

> #### 8.3.2.3 Restrictions on the use of Fields during Initialization
>
> The declaration of a member needs to
>   appear textually before it is used
>   only if the member is an instance
>   (respectively `static`) field of a class
>   or interface C and all of the
>   following conditions hold:
>
> - The usage occurs in an instance (respectively `static`) variable
>     initializer of C or in an instance
>     (respectively `static`) initializer of
>     C.
> - The usage is not on the left hand side of an assignment.
> - The usage is via a simple name.
> - C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the usage.
>
> A compile-time error occurs if any of
>   the four requirements above are not
>   met.
>
> This means that a compile-time error
>   results from the test program:
>
> ```
>   class Test {
>       int i = j;  // compile-time error: incorrect forward reference
>       int j = 1;
>   }
> ```
>
> whereas the following example compiles
>   without error:
>
> ```
>   class Test {
>       Test() { k = 2; }
>       int j = 1;
>       int i = j;
>       int k;
>   }
> ```
>
> even though the constructor
>   [(§8.8)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#41652) for Test refers to the
>   field k that is declared three lines
>   later.
>
> These restrictions are designed to
>   catch, at compile time, circular or
>   otherwise malformed initializations.
>   Thus, both:
>
> ```
> class Z {
>   static int i = j + 2; 
>   static int j = 4;
> }
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> class Z {
>   static { i = j + 2; }
>   static int i, j;
>   static { j = 4; }
> }
> ```
>
> result in compile-time errors.
>   Accesses by methods are not checked in
>   this way, so:
>
> ```
> class Z {
>   static int peek() { return j; }
>   static int i = peek();
>   static int j = 1;
> }
> class Test {
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>       System.out.println(Z.i);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> produces the output:
>
> ```
> 0
> ```
>
> because the variable initializer for i
>   uses the class method peek to access
>   the value of the variable j before j
>   has been initialized by its variable
>   initializer, at which point it still
>   has its default value [(§4.12.5)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#96595).

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that by using the class, the compiler would defer looking for the variable until the class was complete, so it finds y, but if you just define it like the comment it is not yet defined so it fails

Comment: Although I am suprised it lets you do that

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are defined in order of declaration in the class, during class loading. When the JVM will load the `Main` class, `x` will be defined, then `y`. That's why you can't directly use `y` when initializing `x`, you create something that's called a *forward reference*, you refers to a variable not currently defined, and that's illegal for the compiler.

When using `Main.y`, I think the following happens:

- You load `Main`, `x` initialization is called
- When you define `x` to be equals to `Main.y`, the compiler sees a reference to a class, so it will end defining `x` to the current value of the member `y` of the class `Main`. It treats this case as if `Main` was a different class.

Note that in this case, when initializing `x`, `y` hasn't be defined for the moment. So `x` will have a value of `0`.

Comment: If you set y in my example to be 10, the x still becomes 0, so even though the class is loaded, the variable is not given its value, just the default.

Answer (score 0):

You're not permitted to do it because it is meaningless. The only possible interpretation is that *y* is initialized to zero, and you already have two ways of saying that. You don't need this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the compiler creates the references of the static variables with default values with the class in the stack, when it's created and then assigns the provided values.