# Using a static variable in java

Tags: java, static, linked-list

I tried to print the stack elements of the Linked List Implementation.

But to print in the order of the stack itself I need a static variable in java.

```
public void display()
{
<STATIC> <here I need> LinkedListImp temp = this;

    while(temp.next!=null)
    {
     temp=temp.next;
     display();
     }

    System.out.println("\n\t"+ temp.element +"\n");;
}
```

But While declaring like this, I am getting an error.

I have implemented the display() in interface concept. Hence I cannot have display(LinkedListImp temp).

```
interface StackMethods
{
    int pop();
    void push(int numberint);
    void display();
}
```

**For example,
If the elements of stack is 1 then 2 then 3.
I didnt want the output as 1 2 3   or   1 (newline) 2 (newline) 3.

Rather I want as 3 (newline) 
                 2 (newline)
                 1  (though it is not required to demonstrate a real stack)**

Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Why do you think you need a static local variable, and what would you expect it to achieve?

Comment: I think a book on basic language details will help.

Comment: Why do you need a static variable inside of a method?  Static in Java means something different than static in C++.

Comment: @Jon Skeet to print stack elements as in order

Comment: @Muthu: That's saying what you're trying to do, not why you think having a static local variable will help.

Comment: @jon Skeet please now see i have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value of `temp` not to be dependent on an instance of `display()`'s parent class (`LinkedListImp`?), then you would need a static class variable.  In Java the `static` keyword marks a variable that belongs to an entire class, not an individual instance.  Static in Java creates a variable that is also known as a "class variable."  By definition a class variable can't be local.  To learn more about static variables see what the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) has to say or check out [this StackOverflow question that has the spec in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699010/java-static-variables).

But it looks like what you are trying to do is use a class's instance, which means you *don't* want a static variable.  You absolutely want the value tied to the class.

To make it work, though, you need braces around both statements in your while loop.  Otherwise you will get a program that loops through all the elements of the linked list and prints out just the last one.  This is because in Java if a block statement (`if`, `else`, `for`, `while`, etc.) is not followed by braces it treats only the next line as the contents of the block.

```
public void display()
{
    LinkedListImp temp = this;
    while(temp.next!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("\n\t"+ temp.element +"\n");
        temp=temp.next;
    }
}
```

To reverse the order here with a loop I'd use a [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and build up a string.

```
public void display()
{
    LinkedListImp temp = this;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    while(temp.next!=null)
    {
        result.insert(0, "\n\t"+ temp.element +"\n"); // put the result at the front
        temp=temp.next;
    }
    System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```

Based on your edit you have added a recursive call to the method, but this is not necessary with the loop.  If you are doing recursion, remove the loop.  In that case recursion acts *as* a loop.  In that case simply print out the item after calling display with the next item for reverse order, or before for standard order.

```
public display() {
   doDisplay(this);
}

private void doDisplay(LinkedListImpl item) {
    if(item.next) // implicit != null
    {
        doDisplay(item.next);
    }
    System.out.println("\n\t" + temp.element + "\n");  // this line goes before
                                                       // the if statement for
                                                       // regular ordering
}
```

Comment: @justkt - your code is skipping display of the first element. Could you modify so we can vote? Thanks. **Edit** The second example you put in is going to do a reverse display of the list elements.

Comment: @Muthu - have you tested my second code sample, by any chance?  Also have added one way of doing it with an extra variable using a loop.

Comment: @Perception - re: the second example - if you read the text you'll see that's **intentional**.  In the paragraph above I provide a textual explanation of how to do either order with recursion.

Comment: @justkt - you can ignore my second edit. I see the OP is implementing a **stack** as a list and wants to print out the elements in order. @Muthu - Take the code that @justkt wrote, put it in a protected method called internalDisplay or whatever, and presto, problem solved.

Comment: @Perception - I've incorporated your last comment. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for edited answer. It does everything the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have a the ability to declare a variable as static within a funciton like C does.  I don't understand why you think you need a static variable for this...

Comment: I have edited my question sorry i had been left recursive call. please now see my question

Answer (score 0):

`static` variables are declared just like normal instance variables with the static keyword. It's illegal to declare them in a method. Also, why not just use `this` instead of assigning it to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

For printing your list in reverse order, you can use a helper method:

```
public void display() {
    displayHelper(this);
}

private void displayHelper(LinkedListImp temp) {
    if (temp.next != null)
        displayInternal(temp.next);

    System.out.println("\n\t"+ temp.element +"\n");;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion works fine. We don't even need a helper method.

```
public void display()
{
    // Displays in reverse order. For forwards order, do it the other way around.
    if (next != null) { next.display(); }
    System.out.println("\n\t"+ element +"\n");
}
```